c言語で、自作のクイックソート関数を使おうとするとエラーになる
AtCoder Beginners Contest (ABC) 227-B を解くための問題をCで書きました。
問題は「与えられた整数配列の要素(最大値は1000以下)の中で、自然数a,bにより4ab+3a+3bと表されない要素の個数を求めよ。」というものです。
まず、4ab+3a+3bと表される1000以下の自然数の配列を作ることにし、その際、後で二分探索を使うため、新しい値を追加するごとにソートしようとしたのですが、そこで自作のクイックソート関数を呼び出そうとするとエラーになるようです。
qsort_1(ref,0,idx); という1行をコメントアウトするとエラーが出ないので、原因はそこと思われます。
エラーメッセージは以下の通り (Paiza.io での実行結果)
Main: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

ただ、このqsort_1関数は以前にも何度か使っており、その際には正常に動いているで、今回は呼び出し方に問題があったのか、よくわかりません。
コードは以下の通りです。
void qsort_1(int* a, int l, int r);
void print_ivector(int* a,int n);
int b_search(int* a,int n,int x);
int readint(char *s);
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax);
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N1 4
int main(void){
    char* s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N1);
    if (s==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to s failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *ts=fgets(s,N1,stdin);
    if(ts==NULL){
        printf("fgets(s) failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int n=readint(s);
    free(s);
//    printf("n=%d\n",n);
    char* s2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(5*n+1));
    if (s2==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to s2 failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *ts2=fgets(s2,(5*n+1),stdin);
    if(ts2==NULL){
        printf("fgets(s2) failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int* a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    int* ref=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);
    input_iarray(s2,a,n,5*n+1);
    int ans=0, idx=0;
    for(int a=1;a<=142;a++){
        for(int b=1;;b++){
            int t=4*a*b+3*a+3*b;
            if(t>1000){
                break;
            }else{
//                printf("%d ",t);
                if(b_search(ref,idx,t)<0){
                    *(ref+idx++)=t;
                    qsort_1(ref,0,idx);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    printf("idx=%d\n",idx);
    print_ivector(ref,idx);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(b_search(ref,idx,*(a+i))<0){
            ans++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",ans);
    return 0;
}
int readint(char *s){
    int i=0,ret=0;
    while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
        ret*=10;
        ret+=*(s+i)-48;
        i+=1;
    }
    return ret;
}
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax){
    int aidx=0,i=0; 
    while(*(s+i)!=0 && i<imax){
        if (*(s+i)<48 || *(s+i)>57){i++;}
        else{
            int bidx=i;
            while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
                i++;
            }
            int t=0;
            for(int j=bidx;j<i;j++){
                t*=10;
                t+=*(s+j)-48;
            }
        *(a+aidx++)=t;
        }
    }
    if (aidx!=n)printf("n!=aidx aidx=%d\n",aidx);
}
int b_search(int* a,int n,int x){
    int l=0,r=n;
    while((r-l)>0){
        int m=(r+l)/2;
        if(*(a+m)<x){
            l=m+1;
        }else{
            if(*(a+m)>=x && (m==0 || *(a+m-1)<x)){
            return m;
            }else{
                r=m;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
void print_ivector(int* a,int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        printf("%d ",*(a+i));
    }
    printf("%d\n",*(a+n-1));
}
void qsort_1(int* a, int l, int r){
    int left, right, d, temp;
    if (l>=r)return;
    d=*(a+l);
    for(left=l,right=r;left<right;){
        while(left<=right && a[left]<=d)left++;
        while(left<=right && a[right]>d)right--;
        if(left<right){
            temp=a[left];
            a[left]=a[right];
            a[right]=temp;
        }
    }
    temp=a[l];
    a[l]=a[right];
    a[right]=temp;
    qsort_1(a,l,right-1);
    qsort_1(a,right+1,r);
}


actorbugさん、motosannさん、BioBIOSさん、ご回答ありがとうございました。
ソートするときにソートすべき配列より1大きいサイズを渡していてしまったことが原因だったのですね。
あと、BioBIOSさんからご指摘いただいたb_search関数ですが、以前に名前はそのままで「ある値以上の要素が現れる最小のインデックスを返す」関数に書き換えてしまったものをそのまま使っていました。

「以前は実行できていた」のも paiza.io で実行していた結果でしょうか？また、可能であれば paiza.io ではなくローカルのコンパイラで試すこともおすすめします。 (オンラインの実行環境ではいくつか制限があり、ローカルでは発生しない問題が出る可能性があるため)

paiza.ioでも、AtCoder自体でも実行できていました。(気が付かないうちにコードを書き換えていたのでなければですが。)ちなみに、今AtCoderのコードテストで試してみたら、やはり同様のエラーが出ます。残念ですがローカルでの実行環境はないです。

とりあえず、呼び出し部分をqsort_1(ref,0,idx-1);にしたら、ローカルで最後まで実行できるようになりました。

その直前の idx++で格納したインデックスでなく、格納した要素数になっているからですかね？

*(ref+idx++)=t;
qsort_1(ref,0,idx);
を
*(ref+idx)=t;
qsort_1(ref,0,idx++);
にしたらどうかな？

コメントや回答への返信は、質問欄に追記してしまうのではなく、コメント欄でやり取りするようにしてください。 (質問はあくまで "質問" の体裁を保つべきです)

原因
malloc.cでエラーが発生しており、範囲外のメモリにアクセスしていることが原因です。
qsort_1の実行後のprintf内でメモリ確保する際にエラーが発生しています。
(なので、printfをmallocなどに置き換えても同様のエラーになる)
以下が範囲外にアクセスしている理由です。

t1をref[0]に代入する。
{t1, 0, 0, ..., 0}
refを大きさが2の領域としてソートする。
{0, t1, 0, ..., 0}
t2をref[1]に代入する。
{0, t2, 0, ..., 0}
refを大きさが3の領域としてソートする。
{0, 0, t2, ..., 0}

ソートした後は、常にrefの有効な領域は0で埋められることになるので、b_searchは常に-1を返します。
よって、1001個以上の要素を追加およびソートすることで、mallocで確保した領域外にアクセスしてしまっています。
actorbugさんがおっしゃっているようにqsort_1(ref, 0, idx-1)にするとよいと思います。
（b_searchの2分探索の実装が間違っているので、正しい答えはでないと思います。）
